# Setting up openssh-server never end

Tags: ssh, debian, openssl, apt

I've a really annoying issue that impeach to install any package with dpkg.

```
$ dpkg --configure -a
Setting up openssh-server (1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.13) ...
```

...never end.

This is a remote server and I'm not really experienced so It stress me to reinstall OpenSSH, I don't want to loose my ssh access permanently...

**1.** Is it possible to get a more verbose output to figure out what's going on ?

**2.** What Can I do for debug a problem like this ?

**3.** What does Setting Up OpenSSH Server exactly ? Do you see any reason why it is stuck like that ?

I'm aware that my question lacks of details but I'm not sure about what I could add. I will be happy to add anything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I had to rename the file

```
$ mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.postinst_backup
```

Then

```
$ dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Just an fyi, for future readers, this is not a fix. 

It seems that dpkg is stuck in the postinst step of the installation process. Renaming /var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.postinst means that any post-installation operation does not happen, which is not good.